# How to set a dynamic background in Android (just like Tumblr Login UI)

Tags: android, animation, user-interface, background

I am new to Android and I having troubles setting a dynamic background just like Tumblr login UI,

The link below is where I got some help.
[Set Animated .GIF As Background Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842901/set-animated-gif-as-background-android)

But it only works when I load small-size animation, or I have to drop lots of frames of a GIF animation which leads to incoherence. 
If I load all the frames which will cause OutOfMemoryError, I don't think it's the right way.

Is tumblr uses GIF animation or it's actually a short video?

Comment: Try using this library: https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable

Answer (score 1):

I know that Twitter converts all GIFs to MP4. Video compression is far better than GIFs leading to smoother playback and reduced bandwidth and happy users :) Is using MP4s an option?

More on the subject [here.](http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/19/gasp-twitter-gifs-arent-actually-gifs/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how long your animation is, or how high res its frames are, but you probably need to look at loading the image frames in scaled down form into memory. The Android docs give a very coherent explanation of how to do this [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) (basically, you first find the res of the bitmap, then load a scaled down version of it appropriate to the device's screen resolution). It may also be that the animation is too long, and you need to look at forcing bitmaps to recycle (using bitmap.recycle()) once displayed.