# How to add image (jpg) background to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I tried to add image background to fragment via xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
tools:context="com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.Fragments.Loading"></FrameLayout>
```

But it doens't work, also when i tried to add it to the activity(Relative layour - the fragment containee)
I tried also:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.ronen.sunplantnew.Fragments.Loading">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/background"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" /></FrameLayout>
```

But it also doen't work
so how can i add background to fragment?

Comment: Your first code is worked for me.

Comment: Use `android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"` instead of `android:background="@drawable/background"` to check validity of your codes!

Comment: it works with android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: You should add a jpg file with name of background to the drawable folder. Problem is related to your file of picture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add background image to activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307090/how-to-add-background-image-to-activity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not support **GIFs**. Use a **jpg** image, or use AnimationDrawable as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15843628/4038549) offers.

In the case of using a **jpg** image, make sure that there is a **background.jpg** file in the **res/drawable** folder.

Comment: i did a mistake, this is a jpg image