# Android how to set background of relative layout as gif with glide

Tags: android, android-glide

To test, I downloaded the following image and put my drawable folder and I could see this as `ImageView` in the center of my activity when I use glide.

[image]

But when I try to `setBackground`, either it becomes static image or gives errors

```
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ImageView ivImg = new ImageView(this);//to hold 

         RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.middleRlayout);//the layout of activityt

            ivImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.middle);//middle is id of img


            Glide.with(this)
                    .load(R.drawable.giphy)
                    .asGif()
                    .crossFade()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.giphy);

            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                //noinspection deprecation
                r.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.giphy);
            } else {
                r.setBackground(ivImg);
            }
```

I edited my code for Mauker's answer:

```
        RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.middler);
        ImageView ivImg = new ImageView(this);
        ivImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.middle);
        GlideDrawableImageViewTarget imageViewTarget = new       GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(ivImg);
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.giphy)
                .crossFade()
                .placeholder(R.drawable.giphy)
                .into(imageViewTarget);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            //noinspection deprecation
            r.setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.giphy);
        } else {
            r.setBackground(imageViewTarget);
        }
```

my load and placeholder is same? and setbackground doesnot accept as paramter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use Glide's [`GlideDrawableImageViewTarget`](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/340/com/bumptech/glide/request/target/GlideDrawableImageViewTarget.html).

It'll look something like this:

```
ImageView ivImg = findViewById(R.id.imageView); 
GlideDrawableImageViewTarget ivTarget = new GlideDrawableImageViewTarget(ivImg);
Glide.with(this)
    .load(R.drawable.giphy) // The image you want to load
    .crossFade()
    .placeholder(R.raw.sample_gif) // The placeholder GIF.
    .into(ivTarget);
```

**EDIT:** Ok, I've misread your question and saw that you want to set the `RelativeLayout` background. My first thought is... you can't set an animated GIF as the background, since the Drawable represents a "still image". You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15842901/4070469) for more information on that matter. You can also check [this related issue](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/659) on Glide's issue tracker for more info.

---

**Second edit:** One possible way of solving your problem is to combine the code above, with the layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <!-- Use this ImageView to load your background image-->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/gray"/>

    <!-- Place the rest of your UI elements here, on this inner RelativeLayout. Like the sample below -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My sample text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click me!"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Your screen will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: It is old way to do it.

Comment: I believe you'll have to find another way of doing what you want. Setting the `RelativeLayout` background is not the only way to show an image. You could use an `ImageView` as a background, and load the image using the method above.

Comment: Your final image is a GIF?

Comment: So, you want to use the gif just for loading, right? Then you'll really have to change your logic. Forget about using the `RelativeLayout` as the image holder, use the `ImageView` instead. Make it `match_parent` on both width and height. and place all the things you want on top of that `ImageView`.

Comment: Gif will be background. i couldnot understand what you meant. what changes if i use relative layout as imageholder? i will put a lot of images and remove a lot of images in that activity and buttons also

Comment: Your placeholder should be your gif. The image you're trying to load have to come from somewhere else. Why can't you set them both to `match_parent`? I don't see why that would be a performance issue...

Comment: i set them both match parent but my activity is horizolntal. i have gif in drawable. so no other place?you use android:src="@drawable/gray" fo background but i dont need it. i only need gif.

Comment: My `ndroid:src="@drawable/gray` was just an example, change it to fit your needs. In your case, just remove that line and use that loading logic on your code.

Comment: I have raw gif in drawable as R.drawable.giphy.(this is load)i will put this inside android:id="@+id/imageView" this for background.(this is into) i am confused about placeholder. it is because same r.drawable.giphy?

Comment: The placeholder image is an image that will be displayed while your other image is being loaded (from the network, for example), and once it's loaded, the placeholder will be replaced with the other image. If you set both to be your gif, it'll only show the GIF.

Comment: i am really gladful. thank you. it is working even if not fitting the screen (some bigger than height).

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad I could help :) I suggest that you read a bit more about [ImageView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html) and [Glide's documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide). Also, [check this book](https://futurestud.io/blog/glide-getting-started).