# How to Set An Gif Image as background of layout in android studio?

Tags: gif

I'm an animated image that contains frame 179. using the rules of xml, but managed to make an animated image is facing the growing support frames. only 20.When more than 20 frames I got the address in the xml code in the test program can be outside on the phone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Animated .GIF As Background Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842901/set-animated-gif-as-background-android)

Answer (score 0):

Android does not support GIFs. As a workaround, Android offers Animation List/AnimationDrawable. You will need to convert the GIF into individual frames [.png files]. I use GIMP for the conversion.

Save them as frame01.png, frame02.png, and so on, and create an animation-list XML file, say, progress_animation.xml

```
<animation-list android:id="@+id/selected" android:oneshot="false">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame01" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame02" android:duration="50" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frame03" android:duration="50" />
```

....

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/frameN" android:duration="50" />
```

To begin the animation, you need to cast the image to an AnimationDrawable, and call start() on it

```
AnimationDrawable progressAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) yourImageView.getBackground();
progressAnimation.start();
```